# How to stop user agent stylesheet override my color style for a longer dropdown list?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome is over-riding the css color of select lists with over 50 items, with the user agent stylesheet value:

```
select option { background-color: #343434; color: #ccc; }
<select id="Period">
<option value="2018-04-01">2018-Apr</option>
<option value="2018-05-01">2018-May</option>
<option value="2018-06-01">2018-Jun</option>
<option value="2018-07-01">2018-Jul</option>
<option value="2018-08-01">2018-Aug</option>
....
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eg5Lomku/

In the fiddle above, the css is only applied to the first list with 49 items.

I've tried altering the DOCType as per other S/O questions to no avail, and setting the css via jquery but that didnt work either.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Stab in the dark, but that CSS rule is odd. It's valid, but what happens if you drop the "select"? You're just trying to set a bg on the options themselves, so it's probably not necessary.

Comment: i am using chrome version 43.0.2357.81 m for windows, and all of the entries for both lists in your example are shown with a dark background and light text.

Comment: i'm not seeing the problem, but on your end, does it work if you add an `!important` specifier? also, you said "as per other SO questions". can you link to some of those so we can get a better idea of the context here?

Comment: Can also confirm it looks fine on latest Chrome and FF.

Comment: Thanks but , dropping the select doesnt affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ah it appears to be an issue with the Chrome Canary developer build (45.0.2422.0 canary (64-bit)) that I am using.

Thanks to all.